# how to run multiple instance of exe in different folder

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows application. Created in vb.net, I want to run my exe file in same computer with different folder.
These both are connecting to same database. In each exe connecting to differnt Ip address,that s what i want to do like this? I have 5 folders PC1, PC2, PC3, PC4 and PC5.

In each folder i want to run same application. So what I did is in solution explore I took project properties, I changed assembly name, I made 1,2,3,4,5.

Is this the correct method, or can I use any other method?

Comment: Pass the folder name as a command line argument.  Using ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory is possible, it is not better by a long shot.

Comment: Instead of making different exe file to connect to different IP address, why not use multi-thread process, your code can be more manageable because it will run in a single assembly. Do you have the code you can share?